# LaTeX symbol now looks fuzzy

Tags: fonts, symbols, pixelated

In a document of mine, I was using the following symbol and command:

```latex
\newcommand{\plus}{{\textcircled{+}}}
```

At first, the symbol `\textcircled{+}` looked normal and smooth like the rest of the math. Now I recompiled the `.tex` file and the symbol looks fuzzy (see the pic below). I get the same in another document and both in the internal PDF viewer and in like Adobe Acrobat Reader. I did not change packages or preferences, so I have no idea about what is causing this.

Any suggestions on how to get smoothness back?

[image]

Comment: Which compile command do you use? You can find clue in the first line of `.log` file.

Comment: I am using PdfLatex but I was using that even before.Nothing suspicious in the log file

Comment: Also, the command might now work well in math mode. However, even ```\newcommand{\p}{\text{{\footnotesize \textcircled{+}}}}``` is fuzzy

Comment: Show the end of the log file where the fonts are listed (pfb and pk files)

Comment: Do you mean this? Output written on "xyz.pdf" (20 pages, 424887 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 459 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 114 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 19669 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 20736 (max. 10000000)

Comment: Otherwise the whole last part of the log is too long. Anyway it starts with the following: Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 25374 strings out of 481191
 464926 string characters out of 2902670
 849135 words of memory out of 3000000
 40207 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 552239 words of font info for 148 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 68i,15n,83p,1543b,1097s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 <C:\Users\feder\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/dpi600\
tcrm0800.pk>

Comment: You're using miktex, it is known to use a pixelated font as default. Either install cm-super (which is scalable and is the default in texlive) or use the lmodern package. And next time please provide a full but minimal example thus that we can see 2hich class and packages you are using

Comment: @dailef I'm agree with you. Is it 2in instead of 2hich?

Comment: @daleif you're right, lmodern solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the log sniplet you posted we can see that you're using MikTeX. To keep sizes down, sadly, MikTeX use a metafont font as the default font. This font is not scalable, and thus at high resolution you see pixelations like you show here

You have two choices

- install the cm-super package, this installs a vector version of the default font. It is also the default font in texlive
- use the lmodern package. This font is similar to the standard CM font, but is a vector font. Though it might not have support for Russian

Additionally, next time please provide a full full but minimal example which others can copy and test for them self. Here we do not know which packages or class you're using.